# Get git log events without keeping a clone locally?

Tags: git, github

We're looking at analyzing our git patterns and found "git log" has everything we need in it.  We pull it down initially to do the analysis but would like to discard the source code afterwards.  For future updates is there a way to git fetch or pull from the last timestamp or commit so we don't have to either

1) keep the clone and just do a "git pull" and then run "git log --since"

2) every time do a git clone and then a "git log --since"

Comment: You can use the GitHub API to do this: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository

Comment: If you just don't need the *checkout*, you could try cloning a bare repo.

Comment: Ah of course... --bare does the trick where source code is not there

Answer (score 1):

@oc11c pointed out that git clone --bare would only fetch the .git folder and not any source code which is what we're looking for.